# Scala-the operation about the String

Tags: string, scala, date, substr

If I have some Strings like this :

```
"2018013108","2018013107","2018020100","2018013119","2018013114"....
```

the last 2 elements of each String represent hours.I want to get such a function: he can make the time one hour earlier and input.For example:

```
"2018013108" will change to "2018013107","2018020100" will change to "2018013123"...
```

This one hour shift takes place only within a year, so one hour ahead of time only requires attention to the conversion of months and dates.How should I code? Thx!!!

Comment: How should you code? You open your best editor or IDE and start writing stuff. Please take a look at [how to ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). This is not a code service, you must show your effort at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- take last 2 characters to get hours
- substract hours by `-1` if current hours is not `00` else your earlier hours will be `23`
- and then the days would be a day before or the last day of earlier month based on which day is today.
- you can maintain a map of ["month to end of days"](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/months/) to get the last day of previous month

Here's how it would look like;

```
import org.scalatest.FunSpec

class SubstractDateSpec extends FunSpec {

  val monthDays = Map(
    1 -> 31,
    2 -> 28,
    3 -> 31,
    4 -> 30,
    5 -> 31,
    6 -> 30,
    7 -> 31,
    8 -> 31,
    9 -> 30,
    10 -> 31,
    11 -> 31,
    12 -> 31
  )

  def formatIt(data: Int): String = {
    if (data < 10) "0" + data
    else data + ""
  }

  def format(date: String): String = {

    val year = date.slice(0, 4)
    val month = date.slice(4, 6)
    val days = date.slice(6, 8)
    val hours = date.takeRight(2).toInt

    if (hours == 0 && days.toInt == 1) {
      val newMonth = month.toInt - 1
      val newDay = monthDays(newMonth)
      year + formatIt(newMonth) + formatIt(newDay) + "23"

    } else if (hours == 0) {
      year + month + formatIt(days.toInt - 1) + "23"

    } else {
      year + month + days + formatIt(hours - 1)
    }
  }

  it("date") {
    assert(format("2018013108") == "2018013107")
    assert(format("2018101000") == "2018100923")

    assert(format("2018020100") == "2018013123")
  }

}
```

### Read about

[scala.String](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html)

[scala.collection.immutable.Map](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/maps.html)

Comment: you don't need spark to solve this solution. The example I showed is in pure scala and scalatest. But obviously yes this code will work inside spark as well